# Keeping floor mats from moving - no hook on car floor

Tags: toyota, interior

Looking for some ideas to keep floor mats from moving.

In particular, my 91 MR2 has no plastic hook on the car floor to hook into the floor mats and hold them in place.

The floor mats I have only have the plastic teeth on the bottom, but it's not very effective and the mats constantly move around.

Answer (score 6):

Find some pin-on drapery hooks at a hardware store. I couldn't find an online image. If you can picture a lower case letter Y. The lower part is a pointed pin that can be inserted in the carpet. This will leave aU shaped piece to catch the mat.

Comment: Great idea, this worked out perfectly actually.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the 'hook' side of a set of 'velcro' hook-and-loop fasteners - these can normally be bought in sticky-back form, stick the hook strip to the back of the mat and it should hook into the carpet and grip quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Or, depending wildly on your mat and seats, attached it to your seat's frame or base. Some OEMs do this, albeit in the typical nice OE way that's hard to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow '91 MR2 owner, my advice is to junk your current floormats and order some WeatherTech mats.  They fit nice and tight on my MR2, no more problems with the mats walking around.  On the driver's side they wedge up against the dead pedal, and that keeps them solidly in place.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers suit, you can very easily pull up the carpet and weld on a spike or a screw or other hook to use for your mat.

Answer (score 0):

Found the under $1 solution.

See: http://forums.nasioc.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2016932

Comment: While this can be a good solution, this is a bad answer. Simply linking to outside content is not welcome (if link becomes unavailable, the value of this answer rapidly goes to zero). Elaborate, quote, post images.

Answer (score 0):

I work at a Toyota dealer, and I've seen some interesting methods of retaining floor mats, especially because of a policy that we move aftermarket mats to the trunk. 
I've seen people screw mats into the floor (not recommended. You can hit wires)
One person used a wire hanger looped through the back of the mat, and tied it to the bottom of the seat.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most elegant / factory looking solution would be to obtain some [Kam Snaps](http://www.kamsnaps.com/Product-FAQs-13.html) and order the ["long"](http://www.kamsnaps.com/size-20-short-long-c80/) variant which can be installed in fairly thick material.  Install one gender of snap in the rear corers of your mat and install the other gender to the rear of your carpet in your footwells.

If you order an appropriate colour (probably B5 - Black or B4 - Dark Gray) they will look professional and I can personally vouch for their robustness.

Answer (score 0):

I found these Eagle Klaw (strange spelling) fasteners through Facebook and installed them 2 weeks ago. So far so good. Very interesting idea and solid construction. Check them out: https://eagleklaw.com